# NuGet Restore Issue: Xamarin iOS CSharp Targets was not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget

I have a Xamarin Forms Android build pipeline on Azure DevOps, locally my applications build without a problem. When the pipeline runs, I get the following error when I attempt to do a NuGet Restore (the ios pipeline uses the same settings and restores without an issue).

#### Error

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found.
```

This is the line it fails at when trying to a NuGet Restore

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" />
```

I was not getting this issue yesterday and I have not made any `.csproj` or `.sln` changes, so I don't know why this issue has raised, appreciate the help.

#### Build agent

- windows-2022
- NuGet 5.9.1

Comment: Seems like the new Windows images in Azure DevOps no longer have the old Xamarin targets bundled anymore. Seeing the same issue today with our builds.

Comment: Did you resolved this issue, am also facing the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, it seems like there was a change to the agents which now do not include the Xamarin Component in VS2022. You can read more about this in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6082

In that linked issue there is also a workaround, where you can install the Xamarin Component yourself. Note that this adds around 4 minutes extra to that pipeline just installing that component:

```
- pwsh: |
    Set-Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\"
    $InstallPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise"
    $componentsToAdd = @(
      "Component.Xamarin"
    )
    [string]$workloadArgs = $componentsToAdd | ForEach-Object {" --add " +  $_}
    $Arguments = ('/c', "vs_installer.exe", 'modify', '--installPath', "`"$InstallPath`"",$workloadArgs, '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache')
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
    if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "components have been successfully added"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "components were not installed"
        exit 1
    }
  displayName: "Install Xamarin Components"
```

The alternative to this is to switch to macOS-12 agents and building on those instead.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! I literally created a pipeline, and the next day it was failing... and I figured it was a tooling update corresponding with release of Maui workload now "replacing" Xamarin in Visual Studio 17.3. Frustrating that parts of Xamarin tooling on pipeline agents were dropped with the very first non-preview VS release of Maui.